# How to unsubscribe from event handler in SignalR hub proxy?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I am working with JavaScript SignalR client. I open hub connection like:

```
hubConnection = $.hubConnection(url);
proxy= hubConnection.createHubProxy('SomeHub');
```

When I want to subscribe to some hub event:

```
proxy.on("someEvent", function(someData){
    console.log(someData);
});
```

How do I unsubscribe from listening hub event? I tried with proxy.off("someEvent"); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Use `off` method:

```
var myCallback = function(someData) {
    console.log(someData);
}

proxy.on("someEvent", myCallback);

proxy.off("someEvent", myCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

just use proxy.off("someEvent")

without callbackfunction;